# DoTween DoPath's speed between waypoints

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I have a question about DoPath's speeds between waypoints. I want constant speed from start to end but i couldn't achieve that. But speed changing between waypoints.

I couln't find solution for my problem.

```
Vector3 firstPoint = from+new Vector3(5f,5f,0);

pathList.Add(from);
pathList.Add(firstPoint);
pathList.Add(to);


Vector3[] pathArr = pathList.ToArray();

GameObject trail = Instantiate(config.fireWork, from, Quaternion.identity);
       trail.transform.DOPath(pathArr,3,PathType.CatmullRom,PathMode.TopDown2D).SetEase(Ease.Linear).SetLookAt(0.01f).SetDelay(1f);
```

https://gfycat.com/highunknowngentoopenguin

I want constant speed from start to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem, there is nothing wrong with DoPath function. It is about my from and to vectors. My game is 2D but vectors has very high values of Z. So missile seems very fast in 2D. I changed Z values of from and to values problem solved. Thanks @Demigiant for help.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it only takes in the duration of the tween.

You may have to use the generic way: `DOTween.To(...)`.

Get the distance between the current points and divide it by your movement speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `.SetSpeedBased(true)` the duration will represent the number of units the tween moves x second.

P.S.
You can also set `.SetLoops(-1)` execution will loop on path.